# Display mysql rows in html table

Tags: php, mysql

So here is what I did so far: http://d.pr/i/c6z

Code:

```
<tbody>
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
        <?php foreach ($row as $key): ?>
        <td><a href="#"><?php echo $key; ?></a></td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</tbody>
```

and my mysql table looks like that: id (PRIMARY KEY), fullname, username. As you can see, what i'm trying to do is to display all of these records in html table, but what I don't want is href link in first column, just a numbers. SSo, how to remove in foreach loop the first value from the array which is 'id' or maybe there is a better way to do this thing?

Comment: If you don't want to display a link in the first column, why have you wrapped it in an `<a>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
<tbody>
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)): ?>
    <tr>
        <?php foreach ($row as $key): ?>
            <?php if($key === 'id'): ?>
               <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
            <?php else: ?>
               <td><a href="#"><?php echo $key; ?></a></td>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</tbody>
```

Two different views so you have two conditions. It is easier to read for a view.

Answer (score 1):

```
<tbody>
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['id']; unset($row['id']); ?></td>
        <?php foreach ($row as $key): ?>
        <td><a href="#"><?php echo $key; ?></a></td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without commenting on the efficiency or otherwise of your code, you can always use `unset` to unset a specific element of your array, for example,

```
unset($row['id']);
```

will unset the element of `$row` array with key `id` - effectively removing that element from the array.