# Transferring row php to html

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
  <?php
    $trans = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM production.etc");
    $transarray = mysqli_fetch_array($trans);
    while($row = $transarray){
     echo" 
     <tr>
          <th>".$transarray['stock_name']."</th>
          <th>".$transarray['stock_ticker']."</th>
          <th>". $transarray['stock_bp']."</th>
          <th>"."(Need)"."</th>
          <th>".$transarray['stock_shares']."</th>
          <th>".$transarray['stock_change']."</th>
          <th>".$transarray['stock_type']."</th>
          <th><button class='btn btn-primary' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modal1'>Sell Stock</button></th>
      </tr>";
    }
  ?>
```

That is what I have. And my purpose is to be able to transfer all the mySQL data from the database to my website. By transfer each row to echo it onto the html webpage. However, it does what is needed, but it is **creating a row of the data infinite amount of times**, where I just want it to basically loop through the results just once and create one row on the html table for each mySQL row it all within the table. I looked at this, but it does not seem to work when I tried, [Mysql rows to html table using for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29114385/mysql-rows-to-html-table-using-for-loop)

Comment: while($row = $transarray){ is an assignment and is always true unless $transarray becomes falsy which is never the case here because you do not change it. So either the loop never starts (because $transarray is falsy) or it will run forever

Comment: You need to do `while ($transarray = mysqli_fetch_array($trans))`

Comment: @Augwa just tried, now it does not create any of the rows

Comment: Remove the line above the while statement. which is a duplicate of what is being passed into the while statement now.

Comment: use this in while loop $transarray= mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC); and remove this line: $transarray = mysqli_fetch_array($trans);

Comment: @Augwa and Mubashar both method works. I found the problem that cause the rows to doesn't show. Minor bug. Thank you